# react-scripts build Path contains invalid characters

Tags: npm, react-scripts

I have an C# project which builds frontend, which has react-scripts package that builds frontend static files.

I have upgraded react-scripts to version **"react-scripts": "^5.0.0"** and get buid error which shows only when built via c# app terminal

```
 > react-scripts build

         Failed to compile.

         Path contains invalid characters: C:\move\tools\path1st; and so on and so forth.
```

Is there any way to fix problem with wrong paths for react-scripts package, or should I add extra params?

Answer (score 0):

A [relevent issue](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1473) is reported at `nyc`, but it actually a bug in `ts-node`. This [PR](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/pull/1771) might solve the issue.